# Java index json data to solr

Tags: json, solrj

I try to index json data to solr.

```
SolrClient solr = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(SOLR_URL).build();
SolrInputDocument document = new SolrInputDocument();
String stringToParse = "{\"id\": \"101\",\"name\": \"Baia Otel\",\"services\":[{\"room_id\":\"1234\",\"service_name\":\"Shuttle\"},{\"room_id\":\"1235\",\"service_name\":\"Accommodation\"}]}";
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
try {
    JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(stringToParse);
    document.addField("info", json.toJSONString());
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

On **document.addField** method if I use **json.toJSONString()** it indexes json data as string, and when I just use jsonObject without casting it to JSONString;

```
document.addField("info",json)
```

it does not index this field.

How can I index json to solr so that it will be indexed nested?

Comment: Are you using a schema in your collection or are in schemaless mode?

Comment: it is in schemaless mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can find examples of indexing JSON with Solrj for schemaless Solr in this [blog](https://community.hortonworks.com/repos/4422/solrj-index-json-example.html).